# Breaks in Q/KDB+

Tags: break

This question is specifically suited for Q mortals! 
We have **break** keyword in C++ in order to exit from a loop without necessarily traversing the whole loop. 
Are there any keywords in Q/KDB+ that allows me to break from a loop whenever I want to ?


Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So q does not have any key word for creating a break. However, say you wish to debug a function, then you can include the char list "break" within the function to induce the q debugger on execution.

Note, this break can be anything resulting in q entering the debugger, but break is generally preferred for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

you can break the function in q/kdb+ using :(::), for example

```
q) checkbreak: {if[1b; -1 "checking breaks in q/kdb+.."; :(::)]; -1 "break fail..."}

q) checkbreak[]
    
checking breaks in q/kdb+..
```

as you can see, `-1 "break fail..."` do not get executed in the end

Comment: I got how to break from a function. Thanks for the reply !